# how to fetch and save collection data quicker from MongoDB to a csv file in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection in MongoDB with 4,040,989 records.
I am fetching and saving it in a csv in following way-

```
import pandas as pd
import pymongo
connection_string=''
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient(connection_string)
mydb = myclient[""]
mycol = mydb[""]
x = mycol.find()
df = pd.DataFrame(list(x))
print(df)
df.to_csv('Db_collection.csv')
```

The above way is taking so much time (it has been 30 minutes still continues) for this task.

Is there any inbuilt or custom efficient way to complete this process faster with Python?

I am using Python 3.7, PyMongo 3.10.1 and Windows 10 with GPU.

Comment: I have similar issues with `to_csv` or `to_sql` being the bottleneck in my programs. As a matter of fact I am staring at my jupyter notebook which has been showing `ln [*]:` for the past 20 minutes or so as I am trying to get 10 million rows in to a SQL Server database.

Comment: Yes David it's a common issue and there should be inbuilt capability either in PyMongo or any other library in Python to handle this situation. That's why I asked; may be we can get a solution from expert.

Comment: The mongoexport tool provide this functionality.  I don't think pymongo has a separate capability for it.